# xmodmap - L_Alt + ijkl as arrows (polish programmers layout)

Tags: keyboard-layout, xmodmap

I've created following xmodmap file:

```
keycode 64 = Mode_switch (left Alt key)
keysym j = j J Left 
keysym l = l L Right
keysym i = i I Up
keysym k = k K Down
```

it works almost great, but. In polish programmers layout R_Alt + L stands for "Ł". When I'm applying file above R_Alt + L doesn't works. What should I change to have working both - R_Alt + L & L_Alt + L?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write for "ł":
`keycode  46 = l L Left Left lstroke Lstroke lstroke`

You can get keycodes using `xmodmap -pke`.